# iproute2 command to enable a IPv4 address

Tags: networking, ip, iproute

I am investigating how to have **iproute2** commands replace the old `ifconfig` and `ifup` `ifdown` command, and I found out something interesting.

My NIC setup is:

```
[16:07:41 root@vm network-scripts ]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2

DEVICE=eth2
ONBOOT=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

To bring up and down an interface, the old way will be: 
`ifup eth2`
`ifdown eth2`

```
[16:25:10 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip a show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

[16:25:14 root@vm network-scripts ]# ifup eth2

Determining IP information for eth2... done.

[16:25:22 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip a show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb8:13b4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[16:25:26 root@vm-cention network-scripts ]# ifdown eth2

[16:27:51 root@vm-cention network-scripts ]# ip a show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

To use **iproute2** command to do this, normally we use `ip link set eth2 up`, but apparently the `iproute2` can only bring up the link layer of the NIC, but not the IP address:

```
[16:36:25 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip link set eth2 up

[16:37:16 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip a show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb8:13b4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[16:37:20 root@vm network-scripts ]# ping yahoo.com
ping: unknown host yahoo.com
```

But the traditional `ifup` can do that:

```
[16:37:39 root@vm network-scripts ]# ifup eth2

Determining IP information for eth2... done.

[16:39:59 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip a show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb8:13b4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[16:40:04 root@vm network-scripts ]# ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (98.139.183.24) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir2.fp.vip.bf1.yahoo.com (98.139.183.24): icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=243 ms
64 bytes from ir2.fp.vip.bf1.yahoo.com (98.139.183.24): icmp_seq=2 ttl=43 time=341 ms
```

I think this is due to `ifup` bring up the link layer, and also the IPv4 address together.

So my question is: **how do we use iproute2 to enable the IPv4 address as well** ?

**Side note:**
*Interestingly, when `iproute2` bring down the link layer, it doesn't disable the IPv4 address:*

```
[16:42:50 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip a show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb8:13b4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[16:42:58 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip link set eth2 down

[16:43:04 root@vm network-scripts ]# ip a show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth2

[16:43:09 root@vm network-scripts ]# ping yahoo.com
ping: unknown host yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ip` and `ifup` serve different purposes, and are complimentary. `ip` should not be used to replace `ifup`. Actually, `ifup` operates at a higher level.

`ifconfig` (traditional, portable) and `ip` (Linux-only, but much better interface) are two commands that serve the same purpose. They are for setting interface configuration directly. `ip` does indeed fully replace `ifconfig` (and `route` and some of `netstat`) because of its much nicer interface and much wider capabilities, except that `ifconfig` remains for compatibility.

Neither `ip` nor `ifconfig` contain or manage persistent configuration. They apply the request they get on the command line, and that's it.

`ifup` and `ifdown` are for bringing interfaces up and down according to the system coniguration. On some systems this configuration is kept in `/etc/network/interfaces`, on others it's in `/etc/sysconfig/something`. Their job is to read the whole configuration, including IP addresses, routes, DNS servers, custom scripts, etc..., and apply it to the system. They do this (at least conceptually) by calling `ip` or `ifconfig`.

You can manually execute all of the `ip` commands that `ifup` would have used to bring up an interface, but beware that the `ifup`/`ifdown` persistent status information will be out of sync with reality. `ifup` will continue thinking the interface is down even after you bring it up with `ip`.

Comment: Thanks Celeda! That explains my doubt clearly and now I understand the different role of `ip` and `ifup` are playing!

Answer (score 3):

ifup is higher layer tool - which use config files to up and confiture interfaces.
If you wish to do it by ip command you can use something like:

```
ip link set eth0 up # to bring interface up
ip a a 192.168.1.4/24 dev eth0 # to add address to interface
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 # to add default route via gateway in that interface
```

If you wish to auto configure this interface using dhcp you need to use dhcp client - for example dhclient or dhcpcd

Comment: Thanks :) and I think for my case, since it's a dhcp setup, `iproute2` will not able to do this. However do thank for your answer, as that helps when I need to do fixed IP.